# Error: Packages could not have their rosdep keys resolved

Tags: ros-kinetic, ros-melodic, python, rosdistro, python2.7

I am getting an error when I give this command `rosdep install --from-paths ./ -i -y --rosdistro melodic`

```
WARNING: given --rosdistro melodic but ROS_DISTRO is "kinetic". Ignoring environment.
WARNING: ROS_PYTHON_VERSION is unset. Defaulting to 2
ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved to system dependencies:
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: You appear to be missing the critical part of the error message, the list of erroring packages. Please edit your question to include that, as well as what their `package.xml` content. And also how you have setup your rosdep sources. 

I'll note that you also appear to have kinetic in your environment but you're trying to do things with Melodic. This may cause you problems and you may want to remove kinetic from your environment before trying to do more with melodic.

Answer (score 0):

Are there any more details?
something like:
[image]

Then:

```bash
sudo apt-get install package-name
```